# Plotting evaluation curve, does box whisker plot makes any sense?

Tags: python, plot, deep-learning, data-visualization, visualization

I would really appreciate any advice about plotting the evaluation accuracy curve of several models for comparison.

Assuming I have 6 different versions of a model and within each version I have two variations. Normally plotting the evaluation accuracy of these models would look something like this:

[Line plot of evaluation accuracy over N iterations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1JZs.jpg)

It's cluttered and can hardly convey the information. I could clean it up more but it would still be cluttered. Or I could seperate them but would get several plots instead.

Does it make sense to use box whiskers like this?

[Box whisker plot of evaluation accuracy over N iterations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GUhn.jpg)

If not, how would someone go about plotting several models for comparison while keeping it clear and simple?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming in the sense understood here on SO.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you direct me on where to ask such question please?

Comment: I have no idea where this question would be on topic.